# How do you find out who created a private heap?

Tags: c++, windows, heap-memory

I have an Windows C++ application which has a memory leak.  I am pretty sure the leak is in one of our (many) linked libraries.  I have instrumented the global new and delete function in our app and the app calls to allocate memory seem fine. They account for about 10% of the process working set though. 
When I walk the heaps 
// http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee175819%28v=VS.85%29.aspx
returned by GetProcessHeaps()
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366571%28v=VS.85%29.aspx

I can see about a dozen heaps, one of which has about a half gigabyte of allocations in it. Opps!

Ok so HOW can I find out which of the libs are doing it?  Is there anyway to figure out who is allocating the heaps?  I have the handle of each heap.

Comment: `How do you find out who created a private heap?` ... a problem that programmers and parents have in common! :)

Comment: Could always do a binary chop, or try to feed some sample data to each lib...

Answer (score 1):

The straightforward method would be to hook the [`HeapCreate()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366599%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) function.  An example of doing that is [here](http://src.chromium.org/svn/trunk/src/tools/memory_watcher/memory_hook.cc).

Comment: HeapCreate is a windows API that backs new() and malloc. So a straight breakpoint will not work I think.  The Chrome code looks interesting but it is complex and I need to study it more. Thanks Wallyk